# Name hiding when both return type and argument list changed

Tags: c++, name-hiding

My basic question is why name hiding not applicable when both return type and argument list are changed. Please refer below sample piece.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    int f() const { cout <<"I am base void version. "<<endl; return 1;}
    int f(string) const { cout <<"I am base string version. "<<endl; return        1;}
};

class Derived1 : public base {
public:
    int f() const {
        cout << "Derived1::f()\n";
        return 2;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public base {
public:
    int f(int) const {
        cout << "Derived2::f()\n";
        return 3;
    }
};

class Derived3 : public base {
public:
    void f(int) const {
        cout << "Derived3::f()\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    string s("hello");
    Derived1 d1;
    int x = d1.f();
 //d1.f(s); // string version hidden

   Derived2 d2;
   //x = d2.f(); // f() version hidden
    x = d2.f(1);

    Derived3 d3;
    d3.f(1); // No name hiding
 }
```

output :

```
Derived1::f()

Derived2::f()

Derived3::f()
```

In the above program

a) Why string version is not hidden for Derived2 object ?

b) Why name hiding is not applicable when both return type and argument is matched ?

Any links or references for "how name hiding works in compiler level ?" are useful.

Thank you.

Comment: The `string` overload *is* hidden in `Derived2`. You cannot call `d2.f(s)`.

Comment: When I run this program the output is `Derived1::f()
Derived2::f()
Derived3::f()` So we have name hiding in each case? Neither part a), nor part b) of the question makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes @flatmouse . If name hiding is there, ideally derived3 function call shall be restricted right ? since compiler found a name match in base class it shall stop calling derived3 version. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes @Barry. I am confused why and how string call is blocked rather than void function. Basically compiler should match a name to apply name hiding, so it should block void function call when it first finds void function. Is n't it ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you post the program's output?

Comment: return types don't count with polymorphism

Comment: I understood it wrongly. Sorry guys. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

From Bjarne Stroustrup's own [FAQ on this subject](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overloadderived):

> ### Why doesn't overloading work for derived classes?
>
> That question (in many variations) are usually prompted by an example like this:
>
> ```
> #include<iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> class B {
> public:
>   int f(int i) { cout << "f(int): "; return i+1; }
>   // ...
> };
>
> class D : public B {
> public:
>   double f(double d) { cout << "f(double): "; return d+1.3; }
>   // ...
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>   D* pd = new D;
>
>   cout << pd->f(2) << '\n';
>   cout << pd->f(2.3) << '\n';
> }
> ```
>
> which will produce:
>
> ```
>   f(double): 3.3
>   f(double): 3.6
> ```
>
> rather than the
>
> ```
>   f(int): 3
>   f(double): 3.6
> ```
>
> that some people (wrongly) guessed.

You can modify the program in the question to make the hidden overloads available by adding `using base::f;` to the derived class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    int f() const { cout <<"I am base int version. "<<endl; return 1; }
    int f(string) const { cout <<"I am base string version. "<<endl; return        1; }
};

class Derived1 : public base {
public:
    using base::f;
    int f() const
    {
        cout << "Derived1::f()\n";
        return 2;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public base {
public:
    using base::f;
    int f(int) const 
    {
        cout << "Derived2::f()\n";
        return 3;
    }
};

class Derived3 : public base {
public:

    void f(int) const
    {
        cout << "Derived3::f()\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    string s("hello");
    Derived1 d1;
    int x = d1.f();
    d1.f(s); // string version hidden

    Derived2 d2;
    x = d2.f(); // f() version hidden
    x = d2.f(1);

    Derived3 d3;
    d3.f(1); // No name hiding
}
```

The output is then:

```
Derived1::f()
I am base string version.
I am base int version.
Derived2::f()
Derived3::f()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Name Hiding**
- If in derived class member function is given a new definition, there are two possibilities

2. Signature and the return type remains the same

   --- **Function Redifinition** (for ordinary member functions)

   --- **Function Overriding** (for virtual member functions)
3. Signature and the return type changes
   --- **Name Hiding**

   - If a function is given a new definition in the derived class, all the other versions are automatically hidden in the derived class
   - Overloading is not possible across scopes